Azure SQL Elastic Job using Microsoft Entra Authentication with a User-Managed Identity
I need some confirmation, I am creating elastic jobs in Azure SQL.  The documentation is good from Microsoft, but I wanted to make sure I understood the job authentication correctly when using a user-assigned managed identity (UMI).
I understand that you require a Refresh credential that is used to list the dbs on a server.  However, when using database-scope credentials you can also have a job credential and can assign a different one of these to each job step, with the correct permissions in the target db attached to it.
So, my question is when using UIM do you only use the Refresh UMI, since you do not use the @credential_name on the job step creation?  Can you not assign a UMI per job step?

Answer was in the documentation:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-overview?view=azuresql#authentication-via-user-assigned-managed-identity-umi

